# Why are formatting characters like CRLF being rendered by certain browsers as whitespace?

Tags: html, css, browser, whitespace, doctype

I need someone to explain to me where this extra padding is coming from on divs that contain img elements.

You can go to http://www.dev12.com/CSSTest for live examples of my two problems.

**Problem #1**:
Safari, Firefox and Opera render roughly 6 pixels of unwanted bottom padding on the container div.  It does not matter if I explicitly set padding to 0px.

**Problem #2**:
If I format my code so that each image is on it's own line in my html file, an additional 6 pixels of right padding are added to each image.  For example, the following code block renders unwanted padding between the two images:

```
<div>
    <span><img src="button.gif" /></span>
    <span><img src="button.gif" /></span>
</div>
```

However, *this* code block does not have the unwanted space:

```
<div>
    <span><img src="button.gif" /></span><span><img src="button.gif" /></span>
</div>
```

Obviously Safari, Firefox and Opera are rendering my carriage return between span tags as whitespace.  I cannot recall ever having this problem before.  I am writing my code in Textmate.  Is there a setting I should look at to prevent this?

I always use the XHTML 1.0 Strict doctype.  This is particularly confusing to me because it is so rudimentary.  Somebody help me understand this!

KN

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**#1** That's because of the default baseline alignment of inline images - the extra space you're seeing is reserved for descenders (letters that go below the baseline: g, p, q, y, etc.) in the text surrounding your images.  (The fact that you have no text is irrelevant - space for them is still reserved.)

You can get rid of it like this:

```
img {  /* Or a suitable class, etc. */
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

**#2** Newlines are whitespace, and get displayed as spaces.  If you had HTML like this:

```
<p>This is a sentence
in a paragraph.<p>
```

you'd expect the browser to put a space between "sentence" and "in", wouldn't you?  `<img>` elements are inline blocks, just like words in a paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly, the HTML specs say that any and all whitespace in the source file will be rendered as a single whitespace.

For example, if you open up a new HTML doc and type

```
hello
world
```

The result will be "hello world"

The same result will appear for any of the following:

```
hello


world
```

------ or ----------

```
hello world
```

------ or ----------

```
hello                                                 world
```

Regardless how much whitespace you put between "hello" and "world" only one will render. It does not matter if the whitespace is a CRLF or a space character.